# Unslider add .active class to active elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unslider

I am using JQuery Unslider. How can I make it add an `active` class to the current slider element?

http://unslider.com/

I am trying to use this, but it is not working:

```
$('#slider').unslider({
    delay: 3000,
    keys: false,
    fluid: true,
    dots: false,
    complete: function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },
});
```

Comment: are you sure $(this) is always refering to $('#slider') in the complete callback? Try to remplace it by $('#slider').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQb5C/5/)

```
var slider = $('.banner').unslider({    
    complete: function(el) {                
        if(sliderData)
        {
            sliderData.items.removeClass('active');
            $(sliderData.items[sliderData.current]).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});

var sliderData = slider.data('unslider');
```

Comment: This is assigning the whole slider, the class. I need to assign the current slider element (for example, the slider that is currently ON)

Answer (score 0):

That didnt work for me.
I did this on line 187 of unslider.js
just make sure you add the class "active" to your fist slide.
good permanent fix.

```
    if (o.fade) {
                _.i = index;
                ul.find("li:visible").fadeOut(speed);
                ul.find("li:visible").removeClass('active');

                ul.find("li").eq(index).addClass('active');
                ul.find("li").eq(index).fadeIn(speed);

            }
```